# I can't build a static executable in RAD Studio C++ Builder XE

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, static-linking, bpl

I need to build my C++ Builder XE project with linked static library so I can get a large executable file in the Project's Debug\Win32 directory but I can't.

Everytime I try to build my project, it doesn't builds the executable with the Runtime Library whereas I have set the Project's Option to disable the "Link with Dynamic RTL" and enable the "Build with runtime packages" like this:

[image]
[image]

What's going wrong here?
Any idea?

Thank a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You need to turn **OFF** both the "Link with Dynamic RTL" **and** the "Build with runtime packages" options. Dynamic RTL and Runtime packages are all external DLLs.

Comment: I've been turn OFF the "Build with runtime packages" too but it still can produce a static executable. It raise new error message **`[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link`** instead.

Comment: You must **TURN OFF BOTH OPTIONS** in order to produce a standalone executable. A linker error means something else is wrong with your project.

Comment: Done mate, I've been turn off both options in my Project Options but it still not working correctly. I wonder with my project. Any linker Options and Settings are set correctly but it still doesn't work properly.